# Passing methods as parameters prior to Java 8

Tags: java, methods, parameters, program-entry-point

Is it possible to pass methods and parameters? For example, like these;

```
public int subMethodA(int value1, int value2, int value3){
    int A = value1;
    int B = value2;
    int C = value3;
    return A|B|C;
}

public int subMethodB(int value1, int value2, int value3){
    int A = value1;
    int B = value2;
    int C = value3;
    return A|B|C;
}
```

and then I have a another method, in which I want to pass method a parameter;

```
public void MainMethod(Method mymethod, int value1, int value2, int value3){
    mymethod(value1, value2, value3);
}
```

So later on, I can call it using something like;

```
mainMethod(subMethodA, 1,2,3);
mainMethod(subMethodB, 100,2,1520);
```

Is this possibe?

Comment: The best you can do is Java 8's Functional Interfaces.

Comment: I need to work with java 6/7, isn't it possible with these versions?

Comment: It was never possible and still isn't. The best you can do is simulate it with the command pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't use Java 8, this is what you can do.

Create an interface called Method :

```
public interface Method {
    public boolean call(int value1,int value2,int value3);
}
```

Create an implementation of Method called SubMethodA :

```
public class SubMethodA implements Method {

    @Override
    public boolean call(int value1, int value2, int value3) {
        int A = value1;
        int B = value2;
        int C = value3;
        return A|B|C;//This does not compile
    }

}
```

Create the Main class that contains the mainMethod :

```
public class Main {
    public static void mainMethod(Method method,int value1,int value2,int value3) {
        method.call(value1, value2, value3);
    }
}
```

You can now call mainMethod as follows :

```
Main.mainMethod(new SubMethodA(),1,2,3);
```

If you need to pass some other method to the mainMethod, you can also use anonymous inner classes to eliminate the need to create a .java file per method you want to pass :

```
       Main.mainMethod(new Method() {
            public boolean call(int value1, int value2, int value3) {
                int A = value1;
                int B = value2;
                int C = value3;
                return A|B|C;//This does not compile
            }
        },1,2,3);
```

Comment: Cheers, long but this is what I was after. I wish there was a shorter way of doing this.

Comment: I guess that's the only way to do it. You could save the need to create a .java file everytime you want to pass some new kind of method. See my edit.

Comment: It's very common to skip the explicit declaration of SubMethodA and instead create it on the fly. E.g. Main.mainMethod(new Method() {   @Override
    public boolean call(int value1, int value2, int value3) {
        int A = value1;
        int B = value2;
        int C = value3;
        return A|B|C;
    }},1,2,3);

Comment: @Darren I think my answer already covers that. Maybe you missed my edit? I already posted this 6 minutes back ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry about that :(

Answer (score 0):

I confess that I think her requirement very strange, do not know which the intention but perhaps not the best way forward.

Regardless, there is a way yes, using reflection:

```
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
Method myMethod = MyClass.getMethod("myMethod");
Object myReturn = myMethod.invoke(myInstance,param1,param2,param3);
```

You can pass a java.lang.reflect.Method as a parameter and then calls it.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not possible. But if you want, you can use simple design pattern crate.

Like this:

```
class siplmeCrate...{
     int a,b,c;
     public simpleCrate(int a, b..){
          set up abc...
     }

     get abc..

}
```

Then ..

```
return new simpleCrate(a,b,c);
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for but I will give it a try. Thanks.